# Given the index of an element in a triangular array, how do I find its row?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider a triangular array(numbers laid out in rows, where the r-th row contains r elements). Given the index i of an element in this array (assuming the numbers are laid out at indices 1, 2, 3, etc. starting from the top and moving down), which row does that number lie in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last element in row $r$ has index $\sum_{k=1}^rk=\frac12r(r+1)$. Thus, an index $k$ is in row $r$ if and only if

$$\frac12r(r-1)<k\le\frac12r(r+1)\;,$$

or $(r-1)r<2k\le r(r+1)$. In other words, given $k$, you’re looking for the smallest positive integer $r$ such that $2k\le r(r+1)$ or, equivalently, such that $r^2+r-2k\ge 0$. Now $r^2+r-2k=0$ when

$$r=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8k}}2\;,$$

so you want

$$r=\left\lceil\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8k}}2\right\rceil\;,$$

where $\lceil x\rceil$ is the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$.